# GCP multiple external IP bind incoming traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, external

I have a VM to which I have 2 NIC interfaces, each with an external IP address.
The reason for that is that I want one nic listening to port 443 for nginx, and the other nic listening on port 443 for a VPN server.
My problem is that the traffic coming from both external IP arrives on nic0, and I'd like traffic coming to 2nd external IP to arrive on nic1.
Is it possible, and how ?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers
Mael

Comment: When using multiple NICS, the GCP DHCP server sends a default route only to NIC 0. If you need a default route on another NIC, you will need to configure this within the VM instance. I have attached an article that further explains this [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces)

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm :)